# Issue regarding hiding extra columns in datatable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, datatables

I have an existing ruby on rails application where I am using datatable to show table data. Now the problem I am facing that I have to many columns in my database and I have to show all these columns. But I want to represent the webpage in such a manner that only some important columns will be visible in datatable at first and there will be a plus(+) sign on the left of each row and on clicking on that plus sign the extra columns will be added.

I have done quite a few research but I found similar solution when it comes with responsive datatable. But I do not need the responsible feature.

Please help me to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think is can be done using front-end only.

1. Rails backend return all the data,
2. Render the data table using whatever JavaScript lib/framework you like
3. Click `+` button (HTML element) to re-render all the data with the addtional cols